# Invoking the parser with new File in the parse(new File(args[0]), handler);

Tags: java, parsing, saxparser

I just learned to write parser.I need a quick help.I have tried searchign for the same but was not of much help.

I have written all the callback methods.Now i am writing the private static main method to call the parser.

```
    SAXParserFactory parserFactor = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = parserFactor.newSAXParser();
    SAXParserExample handler = new SAXParserExample();`

parser.parse(new File(args[0]), handler);
```

Now my xml name is Employees.xml and i have a class also Employee.java

When i am runing this i am getting this error.I guess i need to send the xml file as argument.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: The name of the XML file is required!
    at main.java.SAXParserExample.main(SAXParserExample.java:82)**

Comment: Why don't you send the xml file name as argument? And what are the `SAXParserExample` and `Employee` classes. Please show us all related information. The xml file content, too.

Comment: @Christian SAXParserExample is my class in which I have written my callback methods(startElement andElement etc.)And Employee class is just like any other class containing 4 fields which are id,first name,last name,salary.
Moreover i have created the handler object and other neccessary things.
But how to pass the xml file as input while calling the parse method.

Comment: I have tried passing like this
`parser.parse(new File("/XMLParsers/src/main/java/Employees.xml"), handler);`

Comment: We don't know how you've organized your project. So verify, that the file exist

Comment: @Christian::thanks for your interest. But i have pasted the exception.It is not with the file exist or not.The file is there have checked it.But the exception coming is that the name of the file is required at the runtime i need to send the name of the xml file to my SAXParserExample Class. More if you want to see the structure and other details please follow this link [SAX Parser](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/java-xml-parser-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

`java Classname Filename.txt`

Hope it works.